# How do I place the cursor at a certain point after sending an AutoHotkey script?

Tags: autohotkey

I thought I'd ask this question here instead of the AutoHotkey forums since this one seems more active and knowledgeable.

I am using AHK for a very basic purpose at the time, and that is to implement a typing color and style, as shown below:

```
^|::
  Send, [b][color={#}4F6377][/color][/b]x
Return
```

It is BBCode that makes the color a bold dark blue. What I am trying to is make the cursor (x) go from the first position to the one shown below.

```
^|::
  Send, [b][color={#}4F6377]x[/color][/b]
Return
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could also use `sendRaw`, so e.g. you modifiers like `^`, `#`, `+` and so on will not be converted into CTRL, WIN, SHIFT etc. but rather be sent literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
^|::
  SendInput, [b][color={#}4F6377][/color][/b]
  SendInput, {Left 12}
return
```

It's using `SendInput` instead of `Send` as it's faster.